# Show that $l_\infty$ is not separable.

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm looking at the proof of showing that $l_\infty$ is not separable, but there is a minor detail I don't understand. In the proof below, is it necessary to define $z_n$ as such instead of simply defining $z_n=x_n^n +1$? I don't understand why we need to separate $z_n$ into two cases depending on the size of $|x_n^n|$, the proof seems to work out regardless.

[image]

Comment: It’s to ensure that $z$ is actually in $\ell^\infty$: it ensures that $\|z\|\le 2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What is the idea to define $z_n$? Is it started from $|z_n−x^n_n|≥1$ for every $n$? So, if we define $z_n=0$, then we have $|0−x_n^n|=|x_n^n|≥1$. And for $|x_n^n|<1$, we can define $z_n=x_n^n+1$ to make sure that $|z_n|=|z_n^n+1|≤|x_n^n|+1<1+1=2$ which implies $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |z_n|<\infty$.

Comment: @MathLearner: Yes, the idea is to make $|z_n-x_n^n|\ge 1$ for each $n$, since that ensures that $\|z-x^k\|_\infty\ge 1$ for each $k$. And yes, you’ve correctly understood the rest of the argument.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the sequence $\{x_n^n\}$ may be unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see non-separablity is to consider the uncountable set $S$ of binary sequences. That is, $(x_n)_n\in S\iff \forall n (x_n\in \{0,1\}).$ The family of non-empty open balls $\{B(s,1/2):s\in S\}$ is pair-wise disjoint and uncountable. A dense set must intersect each one of them.